# Trigger Order Emails Programatically

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have created a module that processes certain order statuses. I have two PDF attachments I need to attach to these orders. These orders are processed after payment gateway authorization so I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger the order email with these two PDF's programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If these emails are associated to a status change (for example from "Processing" to "Complete") you can use [order status emails](https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/order-status-emails.html). For something more complex you will have to write a custom plugin that listens for  EVENT_ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE (or a more appropriate one, according to your case) and then reacts accordingly.